# Triggering model hook when transitioning to same route with same queryParams

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do I trigger my model hook when re-transitioning to the **same** route when you have queryParams that doesn't change (and they are set to refreshModel : true)?

For example, right now I'm in route 'conversations' with queryParam itemCount = 0 which request 10 conversations from my back-end. When I unload a conversation from the store, I now have 9 conversations.

I want to refetch 10 conversations from my back-end (so I always have at least 10 conversations) but with the same queryParam itemCount = 0. How can I do it?

I tried this in my controller where I want to refresh the model:

```
this.transitionTo('conversations', { queryParams : { itemCount = 0 }});
```

but it won't trigger my model hook and I think it is for the following reaons :

1 - I am already on this route
2 - The queryParam isn't changing

How do you force a model to reload? I read about the reload method in my route but I am lost in all this.

Thank you.

Comment: You may try to unload all conversations before transitioning. Or you may try to reload data before transition (using store.find or store.findAll).

Comment: @GennadyDogaev Not a bad idea at all. I will try it and update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Route#refresh](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) method yet? I think something like this might work:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    unloadConversation() {
      // ...
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
});
```